# how to compare two tables in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have multiple table in schema with table names as (`abc201806`,`abc201807`) and (`xyz201806`,`xyz201807`). I want to compare the schema of both the tables. Can some one help me finding the varianace.

sample tables: `abc201806`, `abc201807` is attached as image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should help you out with what you want.

```
SELECT column_name,ordinal_position,data_type,column_type FROM
(
    SELECT
        column_name,ordinal_position,
        data_type,column_type,COUNT(1) rowcount
    FROM information_schema.columns
    WHERE table_schema=DATABASE()
    AND table_name IN ('abc201806','abc201807 ')
    GROUP BY
        column_name,ordinal_position,
        data_type,column_type
    HAVING COUNT(1)=1
) A;
```

Comment: this help you at all?